# NPE when using a bitmap / ProfilePictureView to Bitmap

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to create a circular bitmap from facebook's profilepictureview, but I get a nullpointer that i can't figure out :

```
ImageView fbimage = ( ( ImageView)userProfilePictureView.getChildAt( 0));
    Bitmap bitmap  = ( ( BitmapDrawable) fbimage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
    c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2,bitmap.getWidth()/2,paint);
    fbimage.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

I get the NPE on this line :

```
Bitmap bitmap  = ( ( BitmapDrawable) fbimage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

here is my class (and the full stack) : https://gist.github.com/RidouaneHicham/edce609a4f5aaa59af9a

Thanks !

Comment: Most likely the ImageView is not yet set with a drawable. getDrawable() then returns null and you get the NPE.

Comment: what is userProfilePictureView ? Are You sure that Your fbimage is not null?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i get userProfilePictureView from facebook's profilepictureview widget :         <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
            android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            facebook:preset_size="large" />

Comment: @mach that what i was thinking...but i dont know how to solve i. should i move my code to the updateViewsWithProfileInfo() function ?